# How do I best build up concrete driveway where it meets the basement foundation of house?

Tags: repair, concrete

Our driveway slightly slopes into our basement foundation wall, causing water to stand in that area.  We don't want to simply add cement to this area to elevate it one or two inches because of our concern that the thin layer will eventually crack up, and that the new layer won't bond properly to the old layer.  What is the proper method to correct this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct about the thin layer of concrete not working.  The best way to fix it would be to cut and break out that area and raise it with packed dirt and then pour a new 4" slab.  Preferably giving the water another place to flow like off to the yard.